# Trying to create an activity in which the fontfamily should change when ever the font button is been clicked

Tags: java, android, font-family

I am trying to create an activity that contains an edit text and a button. Whenever the button gets clicked the font family of the edit text should be changed according to the fonts that are been provided in the array list. The activity contains an ArrayList of all the font id in it. whenever the font button will be clicked the if statement will be called that will check whether the font selected is last one or not if it is the last element from the list then it will set the font family and reset the font position to 0 else it will set the font family from the list of that specified font position and increment the font position. This if-else statement will perform the activity to set a new font family according to the array list.
I have searched over the internet and found a solution as setTypeface when I used the solution, it gave an error that says

```
 Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.nanb.alpha/com.nanb.alpha.postcreater}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=4; index=2131296256
```

codes are been provided below:-

```
 ArrayList<Integer> fontstyle = new ArrayList<Integer>(7);
int fontpostion = 0;

private void fontstylemethod() {
    fontstyle.add(R.font.abril_fatface);
    fontstyle.add(R.font.cedarville_cursive);
    fontstyle.add(R.font.alfa_slab_one);
    fontstyle.add(R.font.annie_use_your_telescope);
    fontstyle.add(R.font.aclonica);
    fontstyle.add(R.font.aguafina_script);
    fontstyle.add(R.font.arizonia);

    editText.setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(fontstyle.get(0)));

    font.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(fontpostion == 6){
                //Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),"last element",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                editText.setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(fontstyle.get(fontpostion)));
                fontpostion= 0;
            }else{
                fontpostion++;
                editText.setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(fontstyle.get(fontpostion)));
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Based on what criteria are you selecting the font in the list? Basically, how are you deciding which font to apply from the fonts list?

Comment: Hi! In your code you are using the index _position_, but it should be _fontposition_, isn't it?